# How auto-completation works for custom C++ object created in QML Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I have tried a lot of ways to get code completer suggestions.

If my QML codes are:

```
var a = CustomClass;
a.value = 45; // code completer work but qml error TypeError: Type Error
```

I use this function:

```
var a = CustomClass.newCustomClass();
a.value = 45; // this success with no error but "value" member I typed manually.
```

This causes a big problem if `CustomClass` have many members or attributes. I must look at the class defination and declaration per class object's members typing, if I can not remember, and so my work is slowed down.

*C++:*

```
class CustomClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( QString value READ value WRITE setValue )
    public:
    CustomClass(){}

    Q_INVOKABLE static QVariant* newCustomClass(){ return QVariant::fromValue(new CustomClass());}


    QString value() const { return mValue; }
    void setValue(const QString& value){ this->mValue = value;}


private:

QString mValue;

}
```

*QML code:*

```
import com.customType 1.0

Component.onCompleted: {
var size = Qt.size( 1 , 2 );

size.width = 5; //-> code completer work if typed (ctrl+space). ctrl+space offer me two variable width ve height 

var element = CustomClass.newCustomClass();

element.value = 77; // code completer does not work.
```

*Main function:*

```
qmlRegisterType<CustomClass>("customclass", 1, 0, "CustomClass");
```

Comment: `Q_INVOCABLE` ⇒ `Q_INVOKABLE`